# Google Chrome is half english and half chinese. very annoying. can anyone help?

Tags: windows-10, laptop

for some reason my chrome browser is pretty messed up. I set up an separate account for my brother and his chrome is english and chinese mixed together. on my account, it's just fine! can anyone help?

Comment: Uninstall it and install a fresh install it only takes 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer. So I will assume your are currently logged in with your `Google Account` .

[image: pic1]

**`Note: This is also applicable to Google Chrome even if no one is logged in.`**

Try this one, now go to - `Settings` -> `Show Advanced Settings`

[image: pic2]

And Find the `Language` .

[image: pic3]

Then set the language. And will require for restart.

For your brother or yours do the same. It will apply your pref once you switch account.